# How to extract strings from a string which has bracket?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string like this -

```
(a,b=7)
```

How can I extract a, b and 7 from the above string. I need to pass those values to my constructor.

```
Graph.Edge("a", "b", 7)
```

Is there any easy way to do this? Do I need to use regex for this?

Comment: Most of solutions would use regex like `Scanner`, or `split`. You can also use `StringTokenizer`.

Comment: Anyway is your input always surrounded with parenthesis, or could it be in form `foo (a,b=c) bar (d)`? If second form is also possible then what results do you expect?

Comment: It will always be in the format I mentioned above `(a,b=7)`. Meaning `(string,string=integer)`. But if it is not in this format, then I would like to print the error message and terminate from the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions you could do:

```
String str = "(a,b=7)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?),(.*?)=(\\d+)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));                    // a
    System.out.println(m.group(2));                    // b
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)));  // 7
}
```

Comment: Thanks aioobe. it works fine. But is there any way to look for error cases. Meaning my string will be in this format most of the time `(string,string=integer)` but if it is not in this format, then I would like to print the error message (saying string is not in the desired format) and terminate from the program.

Comment: So add an `else` clause to the if-statement?

Comment: Aaahh.. Pretty simple. Understood now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `string.split` method.

```
String s = "(a,b=7)";
String parts[] = s.split("\\W+");
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(parts));
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[a, b, 7]
```